# Ryhthmbox missing problem

Tags: 12.04, indicator, panel

I have a problem with ryhthmbox,

After update packages, I missed ryhthmbox,

It doesn't exists in panel (ryhthmbox menu) and even in software list . . .

so what should I do? How can I install it again!?? :(

Comment: what happens when you try `sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`? Are you missing the rhythmbox package or just the controls on sound menu?

Comment: Tank u, I installed it frome terminal ... Now I have it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening up the Ubuntu Software Center, finding Rhythmbox and installing it. If Software Center says it's already installed, you can open up a terminal and type the following:

```
gksudo apt-get -y install --reinstall rhythmbox
```

And then put in your admin password (almost always required to install things) and let it run. When it's done re-installing rhythmbox, check and see if it's available again.

Comment: Tankx 4 help  @Mike_IronFist !! I reInsralled it and the problem solved, Now I have my ryhthmbox :)